# Case Insensitive URLs for wso2 Request URL

Tags: url, wso2

I created an api with context MyStudents in wso2 publisher.  So the Request URL is MyStudents/v1.  When I publish this api, I have resource /Students/{name}.  In the wso2 store, when I try out the feature, the URL is http://MyServer.com/MyStudents/v1/Students/foo.  If I keep the case as is in the URL, then my api works.  If I use any other tool to call and change the case in url to http://MyServerName.com/mystudents/students/foo, then I get a 202 error.
Can you please tell me how to make my urls case insensitive in wso2? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

According to HTTP/1.1 specification, RFC2621 section 3.2.3 (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-3.2.3) the path in HTTP URLs is case-sensitive.
So from my point of view the WSO2 API Manager is handling the API URL correctly.