# Disable Case sensitive URLs for wso2 am

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, case-sensitive, api-manager

I created an api in wso2 api manager 2.0 publisher. When I publish this api, I have some resource /Some/things In the wso2 store. If I keep the case as is in the URL, then my api works. If I use any other tool to call and change the case in url to then I get a 202 error.
I know the WSO2 API Manager is handling the API URL correctly but i want to disable these feature.
how can i do this??

Comment: So... you want to *enable* or *disable* case-sensitive URL handling? If the case is wrong you want to ... what, exactly?

Comment: i want to disable case-sensitive URL handling in wso2 api manager.

Comment: Then you'll need to get wso2 api manager to ignore case. Tomcat can't enforce that kind of interpretation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Case Insensitive URLs for wso2 Request URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26087790/case-insensitive-urls-for-wso2-request-url)

Comment: @Dakshika. if you can add duplicate URL into API manager, you should insert URL with deferential case. 
1 - http://MyServerName.com/mystudents/students/foo 2- http://MyServerName.com/Mystudents/students/foo  3- http://MyServerName.com/MYstudents/students/foo 4-...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no option to disable case-sensitive in api manager. But you can rewrite the request url by any reverse proxy and send the request to apim.
e.g nginx url redirect[1]

[1] https://www.nginx.com/blog/creating-nginx-rewrite-rules/